# How load dynamic and well separeted part of views with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have an architectural problem that I can't find an angular-oriented solution. My application has several objects that interact through modals.

#### For Example:

I can create a new color from functionality of colors management.  My creation works through a modal, and in this case the modal will refresh the list of colors behind it.

But when I create a new product I also can create color through this SAME modal. In this case, the modal will refresh my product screen.

With the url and using ajax I can append this modals in html and work with any modal that my system provides in anywhere.

I want to give a different callback for each kind of caller, if possible through the digest cycle of the angular caller scope. But I want to keep my modal independent of the caller.

Note: I don't know the modals that my functionality will need on load, i just know it when the user interacts with the links.

Could I do something like this with angular ?

#### Here some example:

```
$(function() {
    $('.js-content-link').click(function() {
        //here normally is a ajax request with parameters
        var url = $(this).data('file');
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('#main-content').html(data);
            $('.js-modal-link').click(onClickModalLink);
        });
    });

    var loadModal = function(html) {
        $('#modal-content').html(html);
        $('.js-modal-link').click(onClickModalLink);
    };

    var onClickModalLink = function() {
        //here normally is a ajax request with parameters
        $.get($(this).data('file'), loadModal);
    };
})
```

#### Plnkr link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/rJdfGC?p=preview

Comment: Please post your codes...

Comment: Please read the docs [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question so we could help you.